# Unity | CircleCollider2D.radius returning same value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, gravity

I have a project on Unity where I have a 2D space world, where a player (spaceship) is influenced by the gravitational pull of the surrounding planets. But I'm using Newton's law for gravity (F=G*((M*m)/r^2)), and the problem with this is that the gravitational pull will be active throughout the whole level.

So I'm using the Sphere of influence to get a limit as to where the gravity would stop influencing the spaceship, and to do this it requires me to have the radius of the Planet.

The problem is that my Planets don't all have the same size (or "scale"), but the prefabs do. So the CircleCollider component has a radius of 1.5 referring to the original scale. No matter the scale, it stays the same, even when I rescale it manually, the collider gets bigger with it in the scene view, but the value is the same.

So let's say I have Planet1 with a scale of (20,20,20), and Planet2 with a scale of (10,10,10). They have different scales, but their CircleCollider has a value of 1.5, even though it is clearly twice as big in the scene view.

I've looked everywhere and I still haven't found a way of adjusting the CircleCollider.radius value to the scale of the Planet.
I don't necessarily need to get the CircleCollider radius, but just the Planet radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I understood colliders visually are correct size so they will work correctly but you trying to get its value and it is returning some kind of local value. So just multiply it by scale!

```
Vector3 scl = gameObject.transform.scale();
float colliderRadius = radius*scl;
```

Note: I dont have Unity opened so it is more like pseudo-code.

Comment: And when you game will be ready I would like to play in it. Also if you want some more help in development, I can use some of my time =)

Comment: In a more Unity(ish) syntax, I should be wrinting: 

`Vector3 scl = Planet.transform.localScale();
float colliderRadius = radius*scl;`

but the problem is that `Transform` doesn't have a definition for `localScale`

Comment: The correct syntax for localScale is: `transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.1F, 0, 0);`. And I would be glad to post the link to the game ;)

Comment: I'll modify your answer to match the syntax and my script